# How could I decrease time complexity of these loops in Java

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

So I have a method that has takes an array of devices with unique addresses and a device ID as their index and an array of queries. A device is in a query if the query is a prefix of the device address.

For each query, I am meant to find the closest device (through number of hops) to the source, calculated through a Breadth first search of the adjacency list.

Time complexity specification: use D for the number of devices in the network, L for the number of links, and N for the size of the network ( D + L ).

As far as I am aware, the operation below both have a time complexity of O(N*Q), however, I would like to make them O(N+Q). Would this be possible?

```
// For each query, iterates through devices belonging to, finding the min
        for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)    {
            for (int j = 0; j < paths.length; j++)   {
                if (paths[j] < closest[i] && inSubnet(addrs[j], queries[i]))
                    closest[i] = paths[j];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please make more clear the question: There is no D, L or N in your code, also, there is no explanation on how paths and closest are related with queries

Answer (score 0):

I think you can sort `paths` array and then use `binary search` algorithm to find `closest[i]` as data is sorted. So time complexity can come to `Q*log(N)`. Need more info to see if it can be reduced.